# How to set background color of all DevExpress TextEdit controls in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have 10 `Textboxs` then I tried to set background color to red color to all `Textbox` which is blank leaves, it's work but it doesn't set background color by order from first `Textbox` to tenth `Textbox`, I tried to set `TabIndex` too. But it is still doesn't work.

```
#Region "Method"

    Private Function pf_validate_ok()
        For Each tb In Panel1.Controls
            If TypeOf tb Is DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit Then
                If tb.Text = String.Empty Then

                    tb.BackColor = Color.Red
                    tb.ForeColor = Color.White

                    Return False
                Else
                    tb.BackColor = Color.White
                    tb.ForeColor = Color.Black
                End If
            End If
        Next tb
        Return True
    End Function

#End Region
```

Answer (score 0):

They can become "out of order" if you've renamed them, or cut/pasted them around the form.

To guarantee order, either create an explicitly array and iterate over that:

```
Private Function pf_validate_ok()
    Dim TBs() As TextBox = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5}
    For Each tb In TBs
        If TypeOf tb Is DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit Then
            If tb.Text = String.Empty Then

                tb.BackColor = Color.Red
                tb.ForeColor = Color.White

                Return False
            Else
                tb.BackColor = Color.White
                tb.ForeColor = Color.Black
            End If
        End If
    Next tb
    Return True
End Function
```

Or search for them by name with a loop:

```
Private Function pf_validate_ok()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit Then
            Dim tb As DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit = DirectCast(matches(0), DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit)
            If tb.Text = String.Empty Then

                tb.BackColor = Color.Red
                tb.ForeColor = Color.White

                Return False
            Else
                tb.BackColor = Color.White
                tb.ForeColor = Color.Black
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

You'll need to change the names in the Array or in the Controls.Find() call to match your particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your `TextBox's` by `TextBox.Top` and `TextBox.Left` properties to get the right order.
Here is example with `LINQ`:

```
Dim textBoxs = From textBox In Panel1.Controls
               Where TypeOf textBox Is DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit
               Order By textBox.Top, textBox.Left
               Select DirectCast(textBox, DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit)

For Each textBox In textBoxs
    If textBox.Text = String.Empty Then
        textBox.BackColor = Color.Red
        textBox.ForeColor = Color.White

        Return False
    Else
        textBox.BackColor = Color.White
        textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If
Next textBox
```